# Invoking shell-command from function in interactive IPython shell

Tags: python, function, shell, ipython

I have just been playing around with IPython. Currently I am wondering how it would be possible to run a shell-command with a python variable within a function. For example:

```
def x(go):
    return !ls -la {go}

x("*.rar")
```

This gives me "sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected". Could anybody please give me a clue on how to let my "x"-function invoke ls like "ls -la *.rar"? There are *.rar files in my working directory.

Thank you in advance, 
  Rainer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the `history` command output, you'll see that to call external programs ipython uses `_ip.system` method.

Hence, this should work for you:

```
def x(go):
    return _ip.system("ls -la {0}".format(go))
```

However, please note that outside ipython you should probably use `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Hi and thx for your quick response! I just tried it and found out, that ''_ip'' needs to be acquired by "_ip = get_ipython()". However, actually that does not parse the output of "ls". I think I will continue to use subprocess.Popen() which is, sadly, not as convenient as "!" in IPython. Cheers, Rainer

Comment: If you assign the result of a system command to a variable `files = !ls -la`, it gets translated to `files = get_ipython().getoutput('ls -la foo')`.

Comment: @jcollado: `subprocess.Popen` is probably overkill for something like this. Have a look at the module-level functions like `subprocess.check_output`: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1878) in the "!" shell access that made the expansion of "function scoped variables" fail. Your ipython's version might be affected.

You can avoid it by doing yourself the variable expansion:

```
def x(go):
    return get_ipython().getoutput("ls -la {0}".format(go))
```

Answer (score 0):

While subprocess.Popen is probably the way to go as @jcollado said, just for completeness there is the os.system command to immediately send a command to the shell.  However, the subprocess module is almost always a better choice than os.system or os.spawn.

Also, depending on what you are trying to do you may want to use python commands to interact with the operating system rather than passing commands out to a shell.  If you want to deal with lists of files for instance, os.walk would likely result in cleaner and more portable code than grabbing the directory list through shell commands.  You can look at the documentation for Python's OS module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wanted to accomplish, this may be the better way:

```
In [50]:  %alias x ls -la %l


In [51]:  x *.rar

          -rw-r--r-- 1 dubbaluga users 45254 Apr  4 15:12 schoolbus.rar
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its easier to use Python for this case:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.rar')
```